# Screen flow to update account

Tags: visual-workflow

I am new to flows. I have requirement where I need to update account record by using  screen flow. We receive account record id as input and query the account fields and show them in the screen with record values. If any of fields are blank user will update them and click on save. The account  record should get updated.

Could anyone pls help me what are steps i need to follow to accomplish  this.

Thanks in advance...

Thanks,
Anil Kumar

Comment: Check out this [trailhead project](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/build-a-simple-flow) to understand how to create a screen flow.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a spin through our [Tour] and read [ask] and [On Topic](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), then [edit] your question to show what you've done so far and include a specific question the community can answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a screen flow
2. Use a get element to get Account Object Record values
3. Show values on a screen element
4. Accept new values where needed
5. Update Account object record

I have a Youtube channel where I show this kind of stuff step by step. Please go there and check the example with [Get elements and variables](https://youtu.be/nqU07WMY6EI). You can find my channel under the name Salesforce Break - Andy Utkan.